no boot logo on windows after dual boot fedora
I dual booted fedora 39 with windows 11 the boot logo (vendor logo lenovo) during windows boot is black just the loading circle is there.
But when i boot to fedora or screen before grub the logo is there
Is there any way it could be fixed

Why is that logo needed?
